# Kohana 3 Bulletin Board

Tags: kohana-3

I have a site based on Kohana 3 framework. I want to integrate some bulletin board to it. I want to see boards in < div > tag of my site. And want to use accounts of this BB as my site accounts.

What way i must follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Request class?

http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc

Maybe something like this in your view:

```
<div id="mybulletin"><?php echo Request::factory('myurl/method'); ?>  </div>
```